# Ionic2/Horizon error when importing

Tags: ionic2, horizon

I have a (maybe simple) problem. I just want to import @horizon/client in my Ionic 2 app... When I type:

```
import {Horizon} from '@horizon/client';
```

then I get an error: **"Cannot find module @horizon/client"** and second: **"Cannot find module 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!isomorphic-fetch'**. (I also tried with many combinations e.g pointing to **dist** directory but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to a "hacky" webpack configuration which prevents this to work for you.

You can try to use horizon 2 beta in which this workaround is no longer necessary.

If you use webpack, you can install exports-loader and imports-loader, this would also get rid of the problem in the current horizon version.

You also might want to follow these issues for more information/help:
https://github.com/rethinkdb/horizon/issues/477
https://github.com/rethinkdb/horizon/issues/571

Comment: Migration to Horizon 2 beta helped! Thank you! Have a nice day!